# vSphere 5.0 - Custom folders on / are erased on reboot

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, directory

I'v uploaded a folder named scripts with some scripts in the root of my vSphere 5.0 server like this:

```
/scripts
```

When I reboot the server, this folder is not there anymore. Its like if vSphere restores all it's default folders at each reboot.

How can I manage to keep my scripts folder even after a reboot?

Comment: is /scripts on the local datastore? or did you enable ssh and create it in ESXi's own filesystem?

Comment: on ESXi's own filesystem -__-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a diskless or stateless deployment, [this may](http://www.vreference.com/2011/02/10/stateless-diskless-and-feckless/) shed some light on what you're experiencing.  Ideally your scripts should reside in a datastore, not on the root.